# Bogus type parameter makes program uncompilable

Tags: java

I ran into an issue in Java 11 (both in Intellij and on Jenkins) and made a minimal reproduction. A colleague suggests it's a bug in Java.

Of course, the following compiles:

```
public class Main {

    public static class Unused {};

    public interface BaseClass<T> {
        Long pie();
    }

    public static class ChildImpl implements BaseClass<Unused> {
        @Override
        public Long pie() { return 3L; }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BaseClass myObject = new ChildImpl();
        Long piece = myObject.pie();
    }
}
```

But why does the following NOT compile?

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static class Unused{};

    public interface BaseClass<T> {
        List<Long> pie();
    }

    public static class ChildImpl implements BaseClass<Unused> {
        @Override
        public List<Long> pie() { return Collections.singletonList(3L); }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BaseClass myObject = new ChildImpl();
        Long piece = myObject.pie().get(0);
    }
}
```

tip-over screenshots:

[image: Incompatible types]
[image: It's a Long!]
[image: It's an Object!]

Of course in the real project, the "Unused" type parameter is an actual type parameter that's used somewhere else and therefore I can't just remove it (which would be another way to reduce this reproduction to a program that does compile). Can I work that around?

Note: Technically this reproduction is not entirely minimal, because the Unused class can be removed and "Object" can be used as type parameter.

Comment: Does it occur to you that the use of the raw type `BaseClass` in `BaseClass myObject = new ChildImpl();` causes the compile error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You disabled generic type parameters by the following:

```
    BaseClass myObject = new ChildImpl();
```

which should be

```
    BaseClass<Unused> myObject = new ChildImpl();
```

Then `List<Long>` just becomes a List of Object.

As @ernest_k commented I see.